# T-SQL Count all Vehicles that have at least one position with IsGood equal to true in the last minute

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called `VehiclePosition` that contains a big amount of data that is increasing aprox every second.

The structure of this table is something like:

```
VId       | TimestampLocal                     | IsGood
----------+------------------------------------+--------
20        | 2017-08-25 13:17:13.6000000 -04:00 | 1
20        | 2017-08-25 13:17:14.2000000 -04:00 | 1
20        | 2017-08-25 13:17:19.8000000 -04:00 | 0
21        | 2017-08-25 13:17:58.6000000 -04:00 | 0
21        | 2017-08-25 13:18:00.1000000 -04:00 | 0
```

The query should return just VehicleId 20 because in the last minute (13:17 - 13.18) only this vehicle had at least one position with IsGood = 1.

My query

```
select p.VId 
from VehiclePosition p 
where p.VId = (select distinct VId 
               from VehiclePosition 
               where TimestampLocal > GETDATE() 
                     and IsGood = 0)
```

but it seems that loads very slow and returns

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   and I don't know what am I doing wrong.

I'm new in T-SQL queries, so please be gentle :)

Comment: Are you looking for the last minute since the *current* time or the last minute since the latest entry in the table?

Comment: Since the current time

Comment: In `where` clause you should use `in` insted of `=` operator.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn there is no reason to use the outer query at all, since the subquery already returns the correct VId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The marker for a vehicle which should appear in your result is that within one minute of the greatest timestamp value in your table that vehicle appeared at least once in good condition.  If so, you can try the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.VId
FROM VehiclePosition p
WHERE
    IsGood = 1 AND
    TimestampLocal >= DATEADD(minute, -1, GETDATE())
```

I used `SELECT DISTINCT` here because we only want to report each vehicle once.  That is, if a vehicle appeared in the last minute in good condition twice, we would only want to list it once.

Comment: @Dana I updated my answer.  It was not clear whether you wanted data from within one minute of the max timestamp in your table, or one minute of the current time of the query.  Try again and let us know if you have performance issues.

Comment: @Dana Do you have an index on `IsGood` and `TimestampLocal`?  Could this be the topic of your second question?

Comment: No indexes. Just the Id of the row is the PK

Comment: Well consider adding indices on the two columns in the `WHERE` clause.  What you would end up doing in production might differ from this, but indexing these columns should speed up this particular query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from VehiclePosition P 
    where abs(datediff(minute, P.timestamp_local, getdate())) <= 1 and is_good = 1
```

Result (with the current date = `'2017-08-25 13:18'`):

```
id  timestamp_local         is_good
--- ----------------------- -------
20  2017-08-25 13:17:13.000 1
20  2017-08-25 13:17:14.000 1
```

[**Rextester Demo.**](http://rextester.com/SPV38334)